# using map in C++ and providing wrapper functions to use that in C

Tags: c++, c, dictionary, visual-studio-6

In MSVC6 I need to use map in C++ and provide wrapper functions to use them in c only to add,delete and to get size. I want to do this without using any classes in C++. This will be used by threads, Each thread  will have a structure handle which will have a `void *` which will be passed as a parameter to the C++ wrapper functions and I want C++ code to convert this `void *` to a map and do the operations. I am not able to convert the `void *` to a map in C++ any solution would be helpful.

Comment: Show your attempt. Typically it is something small and without that we all can only guess wildly. My guess: ``void Add(void* mapHandle, const char *key, int value ) { std::map<std::string,int> *pMap = reinterpret_cast<std::map<std::string,int>*>(mapHandle); .... }``

Comment: yeah you are correct but am using static_cast to conver the void *. After converting the map variable is not accessible to access it(Access Viaolation)

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna give this a shot, because I like guessing:

I assume you have a function that is passed to the create thead function looking something like this:

```
int callback(void* userdata);
```

So lets make a callback function accessing a map:

```
// In the header file: "my_callback.h" we first need to declare that this function will be used from a C file, this is so the compiler will name the function according to the C standard and not C++.
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Declare your function:
int my_callback(void * map_handle);

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

Now, in the c++ file make sure you include the headerfile:

```
#include "my_callback.h"

int my_callback(void * map_handle) {
    // First, for convenience, let us define the map type
    using mapType = std::map<std::string, int>;

    // First cast the void * to a the correct map * pointer
    mapType *mapPtr = static_cast<mapType*>(map_handle);

    mapPtr->insert( "Test", 1 ); // Insert
    cout << (*mapPtr)["Test"];   // read

    // Or you can assign it to a reference to hide away the pointer syntax:
    mapType & mapRef = *static_cast<mapType*>(map_handle);


    mapRef.insert( "Test", 1 ); // Insert
    cout << mapRef["Test"];   // read

    // (...)
}
```

There are a few things that are worth noting:

1. We are allowed to use `static_cast` because the input is a `void` pointer you should be passing the address of the target map when you create the thread and statically casting to and then from a void pointer to the same type is well defined.
2. This is in no way thread-safe. Special care has to be made when accessing *the same* resource from multiple threads at the same time. If you intend to have only one map and let all threads access that one, you should include a mutex to ensure that only one thread is accessing it at a time. A nifty way to do this is to simply create a small struct including the map and a mutex:

   struct map_n_mutex {
      mapType map;
      some_mutex_t   mutex; // Not sure what the correct type for a mutex would be on windows.
   };

In your thread initialization phase:

```
// Create map
map_n_mutex user_data;

// Create thread (I'm making this function up, use what you have been using)
create_thread( my_callback, &user_data); // pass a pointer to userdata
```

If you go by this approach, remember that you need to cast to `map_n_mutex` and not `mapType` inside the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The C code will need to obtain the `void` pointer from the C++ code, doing something like

```
void *get_map_from_cpp();   /* declare the function */

void *our_map = get_map_from_cpp();
```

where `get_map_from_cpp()` would be defined (in C++) as something like;

```
 #include <map>
 #include <string>

 extern "C" void *get_map_from_cpp()
 {
      std::map<std::string, float> *the_map = new std::map<std::string, float>;
      return static_cast<void *>(the_map);
 }
```

It doesn't stop there though.   To insert values into the map, we need to pass values in, for example, in C

```
  void insert_to_map(void *, const char *str, float f);   /* declaration */

  insert_to_map(our_map, "Everything", 42.0);
```

where `insert_to_map()` must also be defined in C++, for example as

```
   extern "C" void insert_to_map(void *m, const char *str, float f)
   {
        std::map<std::string, float> *the_map;

        the_map = static_cast< std::map<std::string, float> *>(m);
        std::string the_str(str);
        (*the_map)[the_str] = f;
   }
```

Similarly, a `retrieve_from_map()` might be implemented as

```
 extern "C" float retrieve_from_map(void *m, const char *str)
 {
      std::map<std::string, float> *the_map;

      the_map = static_cast< std::map<std::string, float> *>(m);
      std::string the_str(str);

      std::map<std::string, float>::const_iterator i = the_map->find(the_str);
      if (i != the_map->end())
          return i->second;
      else
          return 0.0f;     // string not found in map, so return 0.0
 }
```

The functions called from C must provide a C-only interface - this means C code cannot directly touch C++ types.   Second, the mapping to C++ must be done in exclusively in C++ code, since a C compiler will not understand the constructs.    That means the functions must accept or return only types that make sense in C, the functions must be declared as `extern "C"` for the C++ compiler (so they can be called from C), and the body of the function must handle the mapping from the C types to C++.

This does rely on compatibility between the C and C++ compilers (e.g. from the same vendor, compatible ABI, etc).

Comment: yes but the prob is after converting the map variable not able to access it. In C++ File                                                                                   extern "C" int wrapper_add_workid_to_map(void *maphnd,int key, int value)
{
 std::map<int,int> *pMap = static_cast<std::map<int,int>*>(maphnd);
 (*pMap)[key] = value;
 return 0;
}
 and In C File typedef struct threadhandle
{
 void *workid_map;// this hold the prototype to map handle
}thrhnd;  ret = wrapper_add_workid_to_map(hnd.workid_map,1,1);

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to access it"?   Your code does not that clear.

Comment: not able to access the casted map variable "the_map, means not able to insert or delete values to this map variable "Access Violation errror is thrown".